# Как не вводить цифры 7 и 8 при заполнении номера телефона JQ Masked Input?

Tags: jquery, inputmask

```
$(function(){
    $('.js-phone-field').mask('999-999-99-99');
});
```

Нужно что бы цифры 7 и 8 не входили в input при наборе... естественно если это первая 7 или 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
    $(function(){
        $('.js-phone-field').on('input', function () {
            let val = $('.js-phone-field').val();
            if (val[0] == 8 || val[0] == 7){
                $('.js-phone-field').val(val.slice(1));
            }
        });
        $('.js-phone-field').mask('999-999-99-99');
    });
```

```html
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<input class="js-phone-field">
```

Или используя `maskedinput` таким образом:

```
    $.mask.definitions['h'] = "[0-6-9]";
    $(".js-phone-field").mask("h99-999-99-99");
```

Comment: Теперь разрешает вводить буквы, не вводит в поле а маску заполняет оставляя ---. Спасибо)

Comment: надо что бы заработало с либой:
jquery.maskedinput 1.4.1

https://jsbin.com/yipoxubudo/edit?html,js,output
никак не хочет заводиться(

Comment: @Александр Подскажите, что Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: чуть выше написал

Comment: с другими работает, а именно с этой не хочет :(

Comment: @Александр, Да. Так как у Вас был указан mask, предположил, что это mask, а не. В Вашем случае Вы можете использовать проще конструкцию `$.mask.definitions['h'] = "[0-6-9]";
    $(".js-phone-field").mask("h99-999-99-99");`

Comment: @Denis640Kb код города Нижний Новгород (+7 8312) - если только российские мобильные то $.mask.definitions['h'] = "[9]";